# Gmail filter with multiple emails

Tags: gmail-filters

I'm creating an email filter for archiving and tagging emails.

If I add manually one emails, it works perfect, but if I add multiple mails from a group from my Google Contact List (all done from the Gmail filter modal), the filter is created correctly but it does not work.

Is there any max quantity of added emails or something similar?